# I have a stack navigator using react-navigation 3.3.0 and I want to have a drawer navigation for a specific screen

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to make an iOS mobile app with react native. Right now, I have a stack navigator in App.js

```
export const Navigation = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator({
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
    Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
    Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
    Screen4: { screen: Screen4 },
  }),
)
```

I would like to have a drawer navigator for screen 4 on the left button on header instead of a back button. I tried to follow examples but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Drawer navigator like this,

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
Screen4: { screen: Screen4 }
}
```

Then use this DrawerNavigator in your stack navigator like,

```
export const Navigation = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator({
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
    Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
    Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
    drawer:DrawerNavigator ,
  }),
)
```

Comment: thank you @Siddharth. Do you know how I can change the back button to my own button for the drawer?

Comment: try setting `headerLeft` with your own component in navigation options in the react-navigation.

Comment: Read this link ,it will help you with setting navigation options for headers [configuring Headers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html) @squirreldev .Also accept the answer with ticking it if it helped you